# How to check whether or no XPath and/or XMLStarlet are available

Tags: bash, xpath, ksh

this might be such a simple question, but I have a very restricted access to the internet, and I mostly can only access stackoverflow, and a couple other places.

I've been looking arround to learn how to parse XML, and several comments here point to this two tools. I am unsure about their install methods and/or dependencies, and since I've read somewhere that they might be already installed in the system, I wanted to know how to check this, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to check if any command line tool is installed on your system is to simply try to run it.

So, open a terminal (or other command line interface) and execute `xpath`.

Since most terminals (or other command line interfaces) have auto-completion you could also simply type `xpa` and press `tab`. If it autocompletes to `xpath`, then you know it is installed.

To see an overview of all available commandline tools press tab twice, so `tab tab`.

If xpath is not installed on your system there are probably many possible ways to install it which all depend on the OS that you are running (So, Windows, macOS or a Linux distro).

Comment: I did try to run it, and autocomplete is not available due to (I believe) it being remote console. And my permissions to the machine are limited to say the least, BUT, thank you very much for taking the time to answer, it's always nice to double check I'm not doing something stupidly wrong :D

Answer (score 0):

When I typed xpath I got this response and I am assuming it's not installed XMLStarlet
-bash: xpath: command not found